Using XLOOKUP in a scatterplot series
I am working in a flight manager workbook where a Departure and a Destination airport can be selected. Once the airports have been selected their coordinates are fetched from a different worksheet using an XLOOKUP function.
I want to plot the two coordinates on a scatterplot, so that it appears as a map. The expected result
is as below, plotted according to this table:



Airport code
Longitude
Latitude




FMMI
47.478802
-18.7969


FALA
27.926099
-25.938499



(the axes have been hidden, the markers are the two planes)

This works fine but I want it to be dynamic so that different Destinations and Departures can be selected and their latitudes can be fetched using XLOOKUP.
So I tried to set the markers coordinates to the following:
SERIES($B$3, $E$3, $D$3) and
SERIES($B$4, $E$4, $D$4)

These cells have the following formulae in them: (latitude and longitude are named ranges of the list of latitude and longitude values respectively in a different sheet)

As you can see the functions work properly and fetch the correct latitude and longitude values. However this was what was plotted (I've added the axes for clarity)

So I also tried putting the XLOOKUP formula into the SERIES as follows: 
SERIES($B$3, XLOOKUP($B3,icao,latitude), XLOOKUP($B3,icao,longitude)) and 
SERIES($B$4, XLOOKUP($B4,icao,latitude), XLOOKUP($B4,icao,longitude))
but then I get the following pop-up 

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Define XLOOKUP as a name range works:

Also, even the scope of named range is "Workbook", we still need to put it as =Book6!DataRange in Series:

